# Custom scrollbar on dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, scrollbar, tinyscrollbar

I have a HTML dropdown structure. With the following:

```
 <div class="tl_l">
<div class="labeled"><label for="pers_il">İl</label></div>
<select id="ad_il" name="pers_il" class="">
<option>İstanbul</option>
<option>Ankara</option>
<option>Adana</option>
<option>Adıyaman</option>
<option>Aydın</option>
<option>Muğla</option>
<option>Eskişehir</option>
<option>Konya</option>
<option>Denizli</option>
<option>Bitlis</option>
<option>Yozgat</option>
<option>Antalya</option>
<option>Muğla</option>
</select>
</div>
```

And use [JGD Dropdown](http://www.dev4press.com/jquery/jgd-dropdown/) jquery plugin for i custom dropdown. But my list is too long. So, i want add custom scollbar on this list. Installed [Tiny Scrollbar](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/) and add my HTML. CSS:

```
#scrollbar1 { width: 520px; clear: both; margin: 20px 0 10px; }
#scrollbar1 .viewport { width: 500px; height: 200px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; }
#scrollbar1 .overview { list-style: none; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; }
#scrollbar1 .thumb .end,
#scrollbar1 .thumb { background-color: #003D5D; }
#scrollbar1 .scrollbar { position: relative; float: right; width: 15px; }
#scrollbar1 .track { background-color: #D8EEFD; height: 100%; width:13px; position: relative; padding: 0 1px; }
#scrollbar1 .thumb { height: 20px; width: 13px; cursor: pointer; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0; }
#scrollbar1 .thumb .end { overflow: hidden; height: 5px; width: 13px; }
#scrollbar1 .disable{ display: none; }
.noSelect { user-select: none; -o-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -khtml-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; }
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();

    });
</script>
```

And add scrollbar1 id after opening `select` tag but don't work. When checked any erros via Firebug, not found. How can i use this plugin on my structure?

Comment: When you ask a question that requires this much code, it is often helpful to include a http://jsbin.com/, http://jsfiddle.net/, or http://codepen.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to enable your browser's built in scrollbar, ensure that you specify both the height of the container and the overflow

#scrollbar1 { 
  width: 520px; 
  clear: both; 
  margin: 20px 0 10px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}